# How to run Apache Drill (drill-embedded) and close the terminal?

Tags: apache, apache-drill

I'm interested in testing Apache Drill through http requests, but i want to keep the embedded version of drill running and still close the server terminal.  I've tried the normal backgrounding but Drill-embedded seems to not like that very much.

```
MyAir:apache-drill-1.11.0 me$ pwd
/Users/me/workspace/apache-drill-1.11.0
MyAir:apache-drill-1.11.0 me$ bash bin/drill-embedded &
[2] 10488
MyAir:apache-drill-1.11.0 me$ Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server 
VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
ls
KEYS        LICENSE     NOTICE      README.md   bin     conf        
git.properties  jars        log     sample-data winutils

[2]+  Stopped                 bash bin/drill-embedded
MyAir:apache-drill-1.11.0 me$
```

Is there another solution to standing up a single server install of Apache Drill?  I couldn't seem to find any good documentation on installing a single node of the distributed mode. (Was really trying not to setup a bunch of Hadoop just to test some things out.)

I want to put this Drill-embedded instance on a seperate server... to test some things out.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: (after solved)
I first installed zookeeper from cloudera.

```
yum install https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/one-click-install/redhat/7/x86_64/cloudera-cdh-5-0.x86_64.rpm
```

Then ran

```
yum install zookeeper-server
```

Then

```
sudo service zookeeper-server start
```

Then

```
sudo /opt/apache-drill-1.11.0/bin/drillbit.sh start
```

And myIp:8047 was indeed open. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use bin/drillbit.sh start. You'll need to install
Zookeeper first. This runs Drill in daemon mode.

http://drill-user.incubator.apache.narkive.com/3GNa4weV/running-drill-as-a-persistent-background-process

Comment: I was hoping to not have to install zookeeper, but alas.  The Drill distributed mode docs (https://drill.apache.org/docs/distributed-mode-prerequisites/) say I need a zookeeper quorum.  Does that mean it will run w/ zookeeper standalone mode?